# How to save and preserve both text and checklist items with Core Data in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

How can I achieve something like this (in the Apple Notes app) with Core Data and using SwiftUI?

I am looking to save the exact locations of the checklist items and the text.

So far I can only seem the checklist items but not both the text and checklist items with their exact position.

My Core Data Stack looks like this (only has a name and completed attribute):

[image]

My test right now is only a string attribute.

I can make a list that displays both the text and checklist items, but keeping the exact order of where the text is and where the checklist items are my issue.  Please see the below picture for reference of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help and/or resources you may be willing to offer.

Comment: So you need an attribute for the order? `row: Int` or something?

Comment: This is the second or third time you have asked the same question. What have you tried? How are you filtering/sorting your data? Its it just the checkmark that is the issue? you have two lines that don't have the `Image`. How is the order determined? Chronological? A `created` variable might do the trick that way you `sort` the list by `created`.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to make the checklist part for the text instead of just having rows in a list like what I currently have.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I would suggest adding an additional field to core data of type Boolean called Checklist. Then if it’s supposed to be checklist item then you record as true and if it’s not then you record false

Comment: Then as others have commented you need another field for either a manual order or a date created.  Then in your list, you check whether checkpoint book is true or false to render your circle or not. Does that make sense?